# CakePHP 3.x change hardcoded language via localization

Tags: cakephp, localization, cakephp-3.0, translation

I have a website which uses CakePHP's localization. The website text is hardcoded in Cake's `__('')` function in the Polish language and I have language files for English and Hungarian.

I'm trying to figure out a way to replace all the hardcoded polish strings in the `__('')` functions with their english translation from the language files.

I'd like to do this in order to create content for my website in English and then later translate it, rather than creating it in Polish and then translating it.

I've read the documentation (https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html) and found nothing. The CakePHP translator uses po/pot files. Any ideas?

**Edit**

Hi, thanks for responding. That's not the issue. My problem is that I have `echo __('Polskie zdanie');` in my php file and a .po file for English in '/Locale/en' and a .po for Hungarian in '/Locale/hu'.

I want to have `echo __('English language sentence');` and a .po file in '/Locale/pl' for Polish and keep the hungarian one as is. I want to swap out the language in the hardcoded php file as my new developers dont speak Polish and when they're working on php files they are reading Polish strings in the `__('')` function.

I'd like to swap out what's in my php files with what's in my '/Locale/en' file and then store the polish version in '/Locale/pl'.

Comment: Are You using POedit or another program to generate po/pot files?

Comment: Look at my very old article (in polish) for Cake 2.x, but it's look very similar to Cake 3.x: http://blog.kdev.pl/2013/02/internacjonalizacja-statyczna-i.html

Comment: yes, I'm using POedit @kicaj

Comment: Depending on the size of the project you may want to simply do it by hand. If you want to automate it, then you'll probably have to come up with something on your own, I don't know if there's tools out there for that task, CakePHP at least doesn't ship with anything like that.